# Kubernetes Gateway API - Using HTTPRoute rules to rewrite URI paths

Tags: kubernetes, istio, cilium, url-rewrite, kubernetes-gateway-api

My goal is to have a single `Gateway` that can be used to host multiple applications at different paths. The `URLRewrite` filter exists, however, when it does not seem to be working as expected.

Using Cilium's Hubble for example, I have the following resource:

```yaml
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: hubble
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  parentRefs:
    - name: gateway
      namespace: gateway-system
  rules:
    - matches:
        - path:
            type: PathPrefix
            value: /hubble
      filters:
        - type: URLRewrite
          urlRewrite:
            path:
              type: ReplacePrefixMatch
              replacePrefixMatch: /
      backendRefs:
        - name: hubble-ui
          port: 80
```

I would like to navigate to `http://k8s-ingress/hubble` to access Hubble, `http://k8s-ingress/argo-cd` to access Argo CD, `http://k8s-ingress/foobar` to access Foobar, etc.

However, when I apply this resource and navigate to `http://k8s-ingress/hubble`, I do get a response, but it's an empty page, not the normal Hubble dashboard. (I can tell that the server is responding, however, because the browser tab name is set to `Hubble UI`.

[image]

And if I `curl` it I do get a response:

```bash
$> curl http://k8s-ingress/hubble
<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><title>Hubble UI</title><base href="/"/><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=0,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"/><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png"/><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.png"/><link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/><script defer="defer" src="bundle.main.104f057a7d45238d9d45.js"></script><link href="bundle.main.3818224e482785607640.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><div id="app"></div></body></html>%
```

I assume things aren't working because my server is treating my request like it's targeted at `/hubble` instead of `/`. Which doesn't normally resolve to anything. But isn't that the point of `URLRewrite/ReplacePrefixMatch`? To rewrite the path of a URI before routing to the server?

Perhaps I'm misremembering, but isn't this how things work under Istio? For example the following `VirtualService` spec:

```yaml
http:
  - match:
      - uri: 
          prefix: /hubble
    route:
      - destination:
          host: hubble-ui
          port: 
            number: 80
    rewrite:
      uri: /
```

I've also tried to use `URLRewrite/ReplaceFullPath` but it results in the same behavior as above.

```yaml
    - matches:
        - path:
            type: PathPrefix
            value: /hubble
      filters:
        - type: URLRewrite
          urlRewrite:
            path:
              type: ReplaceFullPath
              replaceFullPath: /
      backendRefs:
        - name: hubble-ui
          port: 80
```

`RequestRedirect/ReplaceFullpath` works somewhat. In that I can navigate to `http://k8s-ingress/hubble` and have my browser 302-redirected to `http://k8s-ingress` where I can successfully hit the Hubble UI. But this isn't what I want, as I would only be able to host a single application on the gateway at `/`.

```yaml
    - matches:
        - path:
            type: PathPrefix
            value: /hubble
      filters:
        - type: RequestRedirect
          requestRedirect:
            path:
              type: ReplaceFullPath
              replaceFullPath: /
            statusCode: 302
    - backendRefs:
        - name: hubble-ui
          port: 80
```